# Copy .so libs to data/app/lib inside device android

Tags: android, .so

I have libexample.so library inside app/lib/arm64-v8a/ and I want it to be copied to data/app/lib inside device upon installation of the app. I know that the android package manager is supposed to do it automatically but somehow it does not..

I have tried enabling `android:extractNativeLibs="true"` but it does not seem to solve it..

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure the .so file is packed into the APK file at all? Analyze the APK file using Android Studio or a ZIP tool of your choice.

Comment: apparently it is not, how do I pack it into the apk?

Comment: May be read the manual? https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/gradle-external-native-builds#jniLibs